# Get rid on 'Are you sure you want to leave this page' on a distant page

Tags: url, popup, alert

I've read many topics here and on others website about this, but I haven't found any solution.
I'm working on a website (PHP/Symfony), and on a click button, it calls a distant URL (action), and the method is Post (I know nothing about that url).

Some functions are running throught that page, and it must close itself. But there is always a 'Are you sure you want to leave this page' alert that I can't get rid of it.

My questions are :

1) How this pop-up appear ? As soon as I have a form ?

2) How can I get rid of it ? I already tried many things like "rewrite" alert function, window.off('beforeunload'), and all solutions that I've read.
I'm running IE 11.

I tried on another website, it seems to work when I have an error with my JS. I've made this :

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  var x = fakeFunction();
 });
```

So fakeFunction() isn't declared, I have an error in my console and I haven't the pop-up. Maybe I can give a tag to my form to execute this JS script with Symfony ? (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html)

Comment: post updated with more informations

Comment: If you need more informations, just ask me :)